# Merging the two tables using sql / Spark

Tags: sql, database, oracle, apache-spark

I have two data set as below and need to merge two data set based on the date range logic. Please suggest any idea? and the driver table is A

```
    Table A     
UID Start Date  End Date                    A_Val
1   1980-01-01 00:00:00 1980-02-01 00:00:00 A
1   1980-02-02 00:00:00 1980-03-10 00:00:00 B
1   1980-03-11 00:00:00 1980-03-24 00:00:00 C

    Table B     
UID Start Date             End Date         B_Val
1   1980-01-10 00:00:00 1980-02-01 00:00:00 G
1   1980-02-02 00:00:00 1980-03-01 00:00:00 H
1   1980-03-02 00:00:00 1980-03-24 00:00:00 I
```

Result / out put needed as below

```
UID Start Date  End Date    A_Val   B_Val
1   1980-01-01 00:00:00 1980-01-09 00:00:00 A   NULL
1   1980-01-10 00:00:00 1980-02-01 00:00:00 A   G
1   1980-02-02 00:00:00 1980-03-01 00:00:00 B   H
1   1980-03-02 00:00:00 1980-03-10 00:00:00 B   I
1   1980-03-11 00:00:00 1980-03-24 00:00:00 C   I
```

[Table Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVQRj.jpg)

[image: Table A and Table B]

Need the out put as below based on date range calculations

[out put of Merged Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBMl3.jpg)

[image: Result of Merged Table]

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: have a go at writing the query first

Comment: also, whats the logic?

Comment: Need to check each row of table B and check whether it is falling under date range or not if it is so need to split or merge based on the result as the out put I have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways, here is one:

- find minimum and maximum date from whole set (subquery `T`),
- create each day entry with hierarchical query (subquery `D`),
- left join data from `A` and `B`,
- assign groups to continuous periods, having same `A_VAL` and `B_VAL` (subquery `G`),
- group data using assigned group numbers.

**<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/363)</sup>**

```
with 
  T as (select min(start_date) sd, max(end_date) ed 
          from (select start_date, end_date from a union all
                select start_date, end_date from b)),
  D as (select sd + level - 1 dt from t connect by sd + level - 1 <= ed), 
  G as (select dt, a_val, b_val,
               row_number() over (order by dt) -
               row_number() over (partition by a_val, b_val order by dt) grp
          from d
          left join a on dt between a.start_date and a.end_date
          left join b on dt between b.start_date and b.end_date)
select min(dt) sd, max(dt) ed, min(a_val) a_val, min(b_val) b_val
  from g group by grp order by sd
```

Result:

```
SD          ED          A_VAL B_VAL
----------- ----------- ----- -----
1980-01-01  1980-01-09  A     
1980-01-10  1980-02-01  A     G
1980-02-02  1980-03-01  B     H
1980-03-02  1980-03-10  B     I
1980-03-11  1980-03-24  C     I
```

If you are doing this for one `U_ID` filter data at first. If for many `U_ID`'s then you have to consider this value in partitioning and grouping.

Comment: Yes , will be having more UID's like 1,2,3,.... ect like the UID 1. we need to group based on the uid's and Thanks for the idea